# Black screen every time I start computer

Tags: bluetooth

[image]

I get this every time I turn on the computer, can someone help me please.

Me sal estoy cada vez que enciendo el ordenador, alguien que me ayude porfavor.

Answer (score 0):

Did you marked option *" install third party software"* during installation ?
It should automatically install proprietary drivers to your PC/Laptop a it's the easiest way. This issue is common. Also, disable secure boot in Bios.